# PHP pg_fetch_* with wrong return types

Tags: php

I have a problem with my PgSQL adapter. I'm using the native driver and the methods pg_fetch_* only return strings, even if the column type is integer or boolean.

For integers, is not a big problem, it's just a simple cast.

The real problem is with boolean values, because it's returned the strings 't' for TRUE and 'f' for FALSE.

Ok, the simple solution is make a verification for this every single time I have boolean fields, but it's not the smartest one...

One specific case is that I want migrate an huge application running on MySQL do PgSQL and would be a lot of conditionals that I'd have to change.

I tried to found something on Google, but (I don't know if I used the wrong keyword combination) was UNsuccessfull.

Sample code:

```
$db = pg_connect("host=localhost dbname=**** user=**** password=**** port=5432") or die("Could not connect");
pg_set_error_verbosity(PGSQL_ERRORS_VERBOSE);
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM mesa';
$result = pg_query($db, $sql);
var_dump(pg_last_error($db));

$data = array();
while($row = pg_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $data[] = $row;
}
var_dump($data);
```

The output:

```
array (size=10)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
    'numero' => string '2' (length=1)
    'max_pessoas' => string '8' (length=1)
    'status' => string 't' (length=1)
1 => 
    array (size=3)
    'numero' => string '3' (length=1)
    'max_pessoas' => string '8' (length=1)
    'status' => string 't' (length=1)
```

And keep going, but 'numero' is a integer, 'status' is a boolean.

Comment: "the native driver". Do you mean the driver built-in to PHP, http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pgsql.php ? If so: What PHP version and which PostgreSQL version are you using?

Comment: Also: please show your code. The PHP and SQL that runs the query, and the PHP that shows that the result is a string. Additionally, when you say something like "I found something on Google" ... *link to it* so we know what you're talking about.

Comment: Sorry... Well, I said I DID NOT find anything on Google, just a comment on PHP manual:
http://br.php.net/manual/it/function.pg-fetch-assoc.php#108957

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood "tried to found ... unsuccessful" as meaning that you'd found something but were unsuccessful at using/interpreting it. My mistake.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like the PHP Pg driver is indeed returning each row as an array of associative arrays with string keys (column name) and string values. I can reproduce this result on php 5.4.7, php-pgsql 5.4.7 and Pg 9.2

Comment: There are no quick answers for your problem since PHP sees all results returned by Postgres as strings. This means you need to know fields types and then cast results in the according type in PHP. This is exactly what Pomm does, it uses a converter system to translate types PHP <=> Pg.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't write it the best way too... Here I have PHP 5.4.6, PHP-PgSQL 5.4.6 and Pg 9.1.5...

Comment: Hey greg... I didn't know Pomm, thank's for that... The problem is that I'm writing my own framework as my dissertation and I can't use 3rd part libraries (tutor's orders)... What I do is map automatically a table through its metadata (a little bit like Zend Framework does), and I'm trying to make it DBMS-independent...

Comment: Well, you can have a look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.getcolumnmeta.php be sure to read all the warnings but it might worth a try. Good luck for your work.

Comment: I'm not planning use PDO for now... In fact, I do can obtain metadata through native driver. It seems like the simplest solution is turn boolean fields into integer fields by casting. I'll have to do some workaround to keep my structure SGBD-independent, not sure yet if it will work... Thanks everbody for your help...

Answer (score 1):

PHP in fact does return 't' for true and 'f' for false.  You need to create your own handling of these or use a framework which abstracts that for you.  Unfortunately that is the way the language has worked since at least PHP 4.0....